# Commit changes missing from git merge

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have two branches, A) develop and B) feature

I work on B, and am now ready to merge B into A.  A has obviously had a lot of work done, with a lot of other feature branches merging in via pull requests.  I pull the latest head of A and for testing purposes, let's say I merge A in to B (Note, I get the same behavior going both directions, but I'm trying to figure out where the problem is).

I merged A in to B, but I have a lot of compiler errors after resolving the merge conflicts.  I noticed that there is actually code included in A that is just not making it over to B.  This causes the build to fail, and there are many things missing (it's at least one large commit worth of code).

I tracked down the commit that I'm having issues "merging" from A to B.  It's not that it's not merging though, I do see it when I type "git log" when B is checked out after the merge. For some reason the actual changes associated with the commit just disappear.  There are no merge conflicts regarding the code in question, and I'm certain I never touched that section while working on B so that anything else could happen.

Regarding the "missing" commit (even though I see it in the branches log), what am I supposed to do to recover the actual changes?  I would use a diff tool, but I'm worried this is a symptom of a larger problem and that other code that I'm unaware of could also be missing.

I'm fairly new to git, so I'm a little unsure of how to approach this.  Please let me know if there's any other information that could be useful.

**What I've tried so far:**

Merging A in to B, commit is there but code from commit is not
Merging B to A, same issue with same code/commit

I've tried rebasing, but the branches are off by many commits with many conflicts.  All commits are also on the server so from what I've read this may be a bad idea.  Please let me know if I should try rebasing in some direction (A->B or B->A).

Comment: As is pretty common, a [mcve] would help, but even without it, just showing the actual command-line-interpreter sequence of commands you ran (`git checkout br1; git merge br2`, plus whatever else, for instance) would help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

If it's just one commit that's missing you can easily apply it to the A branch by issuing a **cherry-pick** command whilst being on the B branch:

```
git cherry-pick commit_name
```

This command takes a specific commit (by name) and applies it to the current branch as a new commit. Just check the name of the commit in your log and paste it as an argument.

Here is some more information on the command:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

**More on the probable cause**

As to the problem itself. There may be numerous reasons why you are experiencing such a situation, some of which may be trivial, some not. I'd say it's most probable that GIT sees the differences, but for some reason comes to a conclusion that they should not be applied (during the auto-merge process). You would have to check the history of B branch, how and when (with regards to this A commit) was it created and does it have any history with that specific commit.

Anyway, if the changes from that commit are not physically present in the B code, a cherry-pick should help you solve this as it will apply these changes with a NEW commit name thus avoiding any problems.

Comment: Appreciate the help, after doing some investigating on which commits (there were two) didn't make it over, I was able to solve my issue using cherry-pick.  The commits were about 1 month old, I'm still very curious as to why the changes disappeared  on a merge, but for now I can at least put out the fire and continue working.

Answer (score 2):

One reason can be you merged A to B previously and handled the conflict in a way that your commit missed.

*Feature* branches which diverged from *develop* for so long can be hard to merge back to *develop* (B -> A). To prevent this, one can merge *develop* to *feature* (A -> B) after some time to handle conflict between the 2 branches so far. In this case when you merge A and B (in any direction) at a later time git dose not mention the handled conflicts again.

To check this, use "git log" on B before the final merge, if you see the missing commit it means it's already merged to B.